# Schema Registry - Confluent AvroSerializer/AvroDeserializer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

Based on the my understanding

Producer : In First call local cache of Schema registry is empty.Then schema related to the object definition to serialize is loaded. then produces looks in the local cache to check whether the schema correspondant to object definition to serialize already exists in the cache , if not , it request to the schema registry .

Consumer:  Schema registry will call every time a schema ID is not   already in the local cache of AvroDeserlzier .

Two Questions :

Now Question here is , If Suppose schema is not being captured in local cache how many times Schema registry will try to store it local during Serialization process at producer ?

In consumer side , Schema registry will call every time a schema ID is not     already in the local cache of AvroDeserlzier for all records ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an infinite cache miss, I believe the HTTP call will keep getting called to find/send the ID again and again, yes, however the chances the schema is not being cached between the first request/response and (de)serialization seem unlikely because they happen in the code very close together. (note, it's open source, so you can verify this as well)